Second Generation Package Test Failures - "Inaccessible Fields" Even When Granting Permission Set
We're attempting to build a second-generation package but are encountering numerous permission-based errors:

Our package includes a permission set, granting administrator-level access to all fields/objects contained in the package:
  "apexTestAccess": {
    "permissionSets": [
      "Assistant_Administrator"
    ],
    "profiles": [
      "System Administrator"
    ]
  }

We're able to successfully build package versions if we exclude --code-coverage, which makes us think it's simply the permission set not being assigned. Any/all advice needed.

When package versions are created, the process involves a separate, temporary "packaging org", created while the process happens and deleted again afterwards. I suspect you have tests relying on the contextual user having the perm set, but that user is a freshly created admin on the packaging org. I recommend you update your tests to use Users created in the tests to which you assign the perm set and which you use in a surrounding System.runAs for the test itself.

What 2GP is this? Unlocked package, unmanaged package or managed package?
